# Find coordinates in a polygon

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-geo-shape

How can I find polygons that stored in elastic index.
Simple mapping:

```
PUT /regions
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "geo_shape"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And simple polygon:

```
/regions/_doc/1
{
    "location" : {
        "type" : "polygon",
        "coordinates" : [
            [ 
                [53.847332102970626,27.485155519098047],
                [53.84626875748117,27.487134989351038],
                [53.8449047241684,27.48501067981124],
                [53.84612634308789,27.482945378869765],
                [53.847411219859,27.48502677306532],
                [53.847332102970626,27.485155519098047] 
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

According to documentation I can only search coordinates within polygon only if the polygon is contained in the request [Geo-polygon query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/query-dsl-geo-polygon-query.html), but I need to find polygons by coordinates in query. Elasticsearch 7.6 version.

Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "filter": {
    "geo_shape": {
      "geometry": {
        "shape": {
          "coordinates": [
            53.846415,
            27.485756
          ],
          "type": "point"
        },
        "relation": "whithin"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right path but your query was heavily malformed. Here's the fix:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "geo_shape": {
          "location": {
            "shape": {
              "coordinates": [
                53.846415,
                27.485756
              ],
              "type": "point"
            },
            "relation": "intersects"
          }
          
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice how I used `intersects` instead of `within`. The reason is explained in this [GIS StackExchange answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/345186/163412).